# How to keep a folder synchronised with an Azure storage account in Python?

Tags: python, azure, io, synchronization, azure-storage

In AWS, a similar functionality exists using `awscli` as explained [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/358). Does there exist a similar functionality in Azure using Python SDK or CLI? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at Azure File Sync - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-the-public-preview-for-azure-file-sync/ (its not python/CLI but I thought I would mention this service in any case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two services `Blob Storage` & `File Storage` in Azure Storage, but I don't know which one of Azure Storage services is you want to be synchronised with a folder and what OS you used is.

As @Gaurav Mantri said, Azure File Sync is a good idea if you want to synchronise a folder with Azure File Share on your on-premise Windows Server.

However, if you want to synchronise Azure Blobs or some Unix-like OS you used like Linux/MacOS, I think you can try to use [`Azure Storage Fuse`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse) for Blob Storage or Samba client for File Storage with `rsync` command to achieve your needs.

First of all, the key point of the workaround solution is to mount the File/Blob service of Azure Storage as a local filesystem, then you can operate it in Python/Other ways as same as on local, as below.

1. For how to mount blob container as fs, to follow the [installation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/wiki/1.-Installation) instructions to install `blobfuse`, then to configure & run the necessary file/script to mount a blob container of Azure Storage account as [the wiki page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/wiki/2.-Configuring-and-Running) said.
2. For how to mount a file share with samba clint, please refer to the offical document [Use Azure Files with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux).

Then, you can directly operate all data in the filesystem of blobfuse mounted or samba mounted, or to do the folder synchronisation with [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) & [`inotify`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) command, or to do other operations if you want.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.